# Data Extract Tar and 7z

Tags: java, apache

I have a single .tar file with many folders and subfolders in it. Inside these many folders there are .7z files among other files. I'd like to search through these folders/subfolder and locate .7z files, (assign them to an array?) and extract them to their respective location.

I'm using Apache Commons: 
1) org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz 
Provides classes for reading and writing archives using the 7z format.
2) org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar
Provides stream classes for reading and writing archives using the TAR format.

1. step I wanna extract the .tar file
2. step I wanna go through the extracted .tar file folder and its subfolders recursively and locate .7z files.
3. In the 3. step I wanna feed the array the array of .7z files I found and extract them 1 by 1 to their respective locations.

I'm having problems in the 3. step with array call/assignment :/ Could you please help? Thank you very much :)

```
    /**
     * uncompresses .tar file
     * @param in
     * @param out
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void decompressTar(String in, File out) throws IOException {
        try (TarArchiveInputStream tin = new TarArchiveInputStream(new FileInputStream(in))){
            TarArchiveEntry entry;
            while ((entry = tin.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    continue;
                }
                File curfile = new File(out, entry.getName());
                File parent = curfile.getParentFile();
                if (!parent.exists()) {
                    parent.mkdirs();
                }
                IOUtils.copy(tin, new FileOutputStream(curfile));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * uncompresses .7z file
     * @param in
     * @param destination
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void decompressSevenz(String in, File destination) throws IOException {
        //@SuppressWarnings("resource")
        SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(new File(in));
        SevenZArchiveEntry entry;
        while ((entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry()) != null){
            if (entry.isDirectory()){
                continue;
            }
            File curfile = new File(destination, entry.getName());
            File parent = curfile.getParentFile();
            if (!parent.exists()) {
                parent.mkdirs();
            }
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(curfile);
            byte[] content = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
            sevenZFile.read(content, 0, content.length);
            out.write(content);
            out.close();
        }
        sevenZFile.close();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        //1) uncompress .tar
        try {
            JThreadTar.decompressTar(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY_PATH, new File(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        //2) go through the extracted .tar file directory and look for .7z (recursively?)
        File[] files = new File(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY).listFiles();

        for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {

                    File[] matches = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
                    {
                      public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
                      {
                         return name.endsWith(".7z");
                      }
                    });

                    for (File element: matches) {
                        System.out.println(element);
                        }
                }
                else {
                    continue;
                }
        }

        //3) Feed the array above to decompressSevenz method

        for (int i = 0; i < matches.length; i++)
        {
            if (matches[i].isFile())
            {      
                try {
                JThreadTar.decompressSevenz(matches[i].toString(), new File(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY));
                } 
                catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is: I can't refer to []matches in step 3. I'm not using this correctly. I just want to create an array []matches for .7z file matches. Every time a .7z is found, I'd like to add it to this array. and in the 3. step I wanna extract each .7z to its relative location.

I came a bit further:

```
    //1) uncompress .tar
        try {
            JThreadTar.decompressTar(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY_PATH, new File(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        //2) go through the extracted .tar file directory and look for .7z (recursively?)
        File dir = new File(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY);
        File[] dirFiles = dir.listFiles();
        ArrayList<File> matches2 = new ArrayList<File>();

        for (File file : dirFiles) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    File[] matches = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
                    {
                      public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
                      {
                         return name.endsWith(".7z");
                      }
                    });
                    matches2.addAll(Arrays.asList(matches));
                }
                else if (file.isFile()) {
                    if (file.getName().endsWith(".7z")){
                    matches2.add(file);
                    };
                    }
                };


            //3) Feed the arraylist above to decompressSevenz method   
            for (int counter = 0; counter < matches2.size(); counter++) {
            if (matches2.get(counter).isFile())
            {  
                try {
                JThreadTar.decompressSevenz(matches2.get(counter).toString(), new File(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY));
                } 
                catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            }
```

Here is after the final form of step 2 and step 3 from @Joop Eggen

```
        Path topDir = Paths.get(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY);
        try {
            Files.walk(topDir)
                .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".7z"))
                .forEach(path -> {
                    try {
                        JThreadTar.decompressSevenz(path.toString(), topDir.toFile());
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
            });
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

1. step recursively:

```
        Path toptopDir = Paths.get(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY_PATH);
        try {
            Files.walk(toptopDir)
                .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".tar"))
                .forEach(path -> {
                    try {
                        JThreadTar.decompressTar(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY_PATH, new File(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY));
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
            });
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Please explain the issue

Comment: In step 2 you write in your comment "recursively". But there is no recursive call. You should put it in a separate method which can call itself recursively. And why do you want to use an array? It would be better to use some kind of list to store the references to the 7z files. An array has a fixed length and you don't know beforehand how many 7z files you will find.

Comment: @vanje Thank you for your remarks! :) you're absolutely correct. I now made an arrayList for 2. step. I go through all folders and files in the extracted .tar folder and check if it's a .7z file. If yes I add that to an arrayList. In the 3. step I iterate through that arrayList. My code is nowhere near perfect. Please advise if you see any improvements somewhere. However I think it works.

Comment: @arcanium0611 I just tried to describe it a bit and wrote some further code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the opportunity to use the newer Path and Files. `Files.listFiles()` may return null. And the usage of Arrays.asList and such will cause heavy data.

All that would be simplified to:

```
    Path topDir = Paths.get(RECURSIVE_DIRECTORY);
    Files.walk(topDir)
        .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".7z"))
        .forEach(path -> {
            try {
                JThreadTar.decompressSevenz(path.toString(), topDir.toFile());
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Joop Eggen works like a charm! only 1 thing the method accepts decompressSevenz(String, File) I changed the 2nd argument to topDir.toFile() and had to add another IOException. Is this fine in your opinion? I added the code above

Comment: Of course; thanks for the feedback; I'll change the answer for other readers.

Comment: Hi again Joop Eggen. I'd like to consult you regarding another change. Now I wanna extend the 1. step of the above algorithm. As in I always start with 1 .tar file. However this time. I wanna loop through the folders/subfolders inside this .tar file, and in case any found, extract the .tar files till there is no .tar file left. Then just on to step 2, starting from topDir, find and extract .7z files till there is no .7z left. I tried to apply the same logic above there but not luck. Would you have any suggestions? I post the code to the end above.

Comment: So in any .7z can again contain a .tar? Reminds me of [Matryoshkas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll). I take it one cannot walk a directory tree _and_  unpack at the same time. Then collect a list of tars, `final List<Path> tars = new ArrayList<>(1000);` and process them in a second phase. BTW I love Unix sync for such data shoveling.

Comment: oh no, sorry for confusing, we take a single .tar file. and look for .tar files in it. then we move on to 7z. So I meant 1. step untarring till no .tar left 2. step in unsevenz till no .7z left.

Comment: so the solution you posted above for step 2 and 3 combination stays the same. I just wanna make sure no more .tar left so we start with TopDir fresh.

Comment: Yeah, viel Erfolg.

Comment: Thank you for all your help @Joop Eggen